# Returning a boolean from event handler args when handler runs an async method

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have this event definition:

```
public event EventHandler<CommandEventArgs> Command;
```

Where `CommandEventArgs` is:

```
public class CommandEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string SomeData{ get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this method to invoke the handler:

```
    private bool OnCommand(string someData)
    {
        var eventArgs = new CommandEventArgs
        {
            SomeData = someData,
        };
        Command?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);

        return eventArgs.Success;
    }
```

Well... the method that is actually invoked is this:

```
    private async void HttpServer_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        using (AttendanceEntities db = new AttendanceEntities())
        {
             // BEGIN of some processing
             //
             // END of some processing

             await db.SaveChangesAsync();  //<----- Problem is at this point
        }

        e.Success = true;
    }
```

The fact is that the instruction `return eventArgs.Success` in `OnCommand` is called before the actual assignment of the property, that is, `e.Success = true`. That is why, when I check return value of `OnCommand`, is always false.

When I debug step by step, and the `SaveChangesAsync` method is executed, execution continues somewhere asynchronously without falling into `e.Success = true`

How can I do that?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: That is how `async` is supposed to work, it saves a state machine of where it is up to and carries on later. What should the thread do, twiddle it's thumbs while waiting for the response?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080500/3791245) to a related question might interest you.  `async void` really will return scope when it hits the `await`, which is the root of your problem.  The answer suggests refactoring to not use the keyword `event` for this scenario.  Perhaps using a single `Func` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the event-raising code (asynchronously) wait for the handler(s) to execute to completion before it checks `Success`. There are [a few approaches](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html), but my preferred solution is deferrals, e.g., [using `DeferralManager` from my `AsyncEx` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Oop/DeferralManager.cs):

```
public class CommandEventArgs : EventArgs, IDeferralSource
{
    public string SomeData{ get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IDisposable GetDeferral() => DeferralManager.DeferralSource.GetDeferral();
    internal DeferralManager DeferralManager { get; } = new DeferralManager();
}

private async Task<bool> OnCommandAsync(string someData)
{
    var eventArgs = new CommandEventArgs
    {
        SomeData = someData,
    };
    Command?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
    await eventArgs.DeferralManager.WaitForDeferralsAsync();
    return eventArgs.Success;
}

private async void HttpServer_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    using var _ = e.GetDeferral();
    using (AttendanceEntities db = new AttendanceEntities())
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    e.Success = true;
}
```

Note that this awkwardness is due to misusing events in the first place. Events are a valid design to use when implementing the Observer design pattern. However, in this case events are being misused because this is a Strategy or Template Method design pattern. In the synchronous world, you can get away with that kind of substitution (using an event instead of an interface with a single method). But in the asynchronous world, that kind of substitution breaks down.